# Java - threads in for loop are not created before the previous one is finished

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to create new threads in a `for` loop in Java, but a new thread is not started before the previous one is done running. How can I make them all start without waiting for the previous one?

This is the code I am using to start threads:

```
Thread[] threads = new Thread[processors];
for(int i = 1; i <= processors; i++)
{
    threads[i] = new Thread();
    threads[i].doSomeWork();
    threads[i].run();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `new Thread` does not actually create a new thread. It just creates a `Thread` object. You have to call `start()` on the thread. But that is also not enough. You also have to tell the `Thread` what to do.

There are two ways to tell the `Thread` what to do:

```
threads[i] = new Thread() {
   @Override public void run() {
     doSomeWork();
   }
};
threads[i].start();
```

Or

```
threads[i] = new Thread(new Runnable() {
   @Override public void run() {
     doSomeWork();
   }
});
threads[i].start();
```

Answer (score 1):

To start next thread, use `threads[i].start()`, not `threads[i].run()`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not indicated any synchronization, the order in which the threads will start is arbitrary and will depend on the particular JVM implementation and may also depend on external factors, depending on what work doSomeWork actually does.